# Finding Max of 3 Inputs VBA

Tags: excel, vba, max

I am trying to find the maximum of 3 inputs. The problem is not in the algorithm, as when I made the same script in python it worked just fine. The problem is that it does not work as expected. I will write some scenarios and what the outcome was:

8 5 12 - Max: 12 
5 8 12 - Max: 12 
12 5 8 - Max: 8 
12 8 5 - Max: 8 
5 12 8 - Max: 8 
8 12 5 - Max: 8 
100 22 33 - Max: 33 
22 3 100 - Max: 100 
100 22 3 - Max: 22

It seems that it works for quite some combination, but not for each and every one. I haven't managed to find a pattern yet, and I can't figure out what is going wrong.

I am attaching the code:

```
Sub Maxthree()
'Calculates the maximum of three numbers'
Dim x, y, z As Single
x = InputBox("Enter the first number!")
y = InputBox("Enter the second number!")
z = InputBox("Enter the third number!")
MsgBox ("X: " & x & " Y: " & y & " Z: " & z)
If x > y Then
    If x > z Then
        MsgBox ("the maximum is : " & x)
    Else
        MsgBox ("the maximum is : " & z)
    End If
Else
    If y > z Then
        MsgBox ("the maximum is : " & y)
    Else
        MsgBox ("the maximum is : " & z)
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that declaring variables as `Dim x, y, z As Single` will declare `x`, `y` as `Variant` and only `z` as `Single`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because they are input using an InputBox, it's comparing text values. So, for example "8" is greater than "12". Instead try converting to `Longs` like:

```
x = CLng(InputBox("Enter the first number!"))
```

You can also simplify your code to:

```
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Max(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Thank you. I also noticed that using CSng is better, as it can use decimals too!

Comment: That's true. Or `CDbl` if you want to go wild :).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pattern you were looking for.

Since X and Y are Variant while Z is Single, this is how VBA will perform the comparisons:

X vs Y:  string vs string  (this is what is causing all the trouble)

X vs Z:  numeric (X will be converted automatically)

Y vs Z:  numeric (Y will be converted automatically)

Re-evaluate all 9 of your scenarios, with X and Y being compared as strings and (X or Y) being compared to Z as numbers. The results you observed, while unexpected, are correct.

Just feel fortunate that you aren't programming in PHP, where this is all much worse!

Microsoft are to blame for allowing Variant to be the default data type if no other type is specified. They support "Option Explicit" to force variables to be declared. They should go a step further, and have an option to require data types in all declarations.

Comment: Haha I was just rereading this post and I felt the need to mention that I am programming in PHP nowadays :P

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://idevlop.blogspot.lu/2016/08/calculate-max-of-list-in-vba.html) is a function that returns the Largest element of any number of them:

```
Function Largest(ParamArray a() As Variant) As Variant
'returns the largest element of list
'List is supposed to be consistent: all nummbers or all strings
'e.g:   largest(2,6,-9,7,3)         -> 7
'       largest("d", "z", "c", "x") -> "z"
'by Patrick Honorez --- www.idevlop.com

    Dim result As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    result = Null

    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If result > a(i) Then
            'nothing to do. This construct will properly handle null values
        Else
            result = a(i)
        End If
    Next i
    Largest = result
End Function
```